# Suspend sending emails in ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

In my Rails application I want to temporarily stop sending email for specific users (e.g. when I get bounces due to quota) until the user confirms he is able to receive email again.

I have a common superclass for all mailer classes. There I always call a method `setup_email` before sending a mail.

Where is the best place to call `@user.mail_suspended?`?

Here is some simplified sample app, I use Rails 2.3:

```
# Common super class for all Mailers
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  protected
    def setup_mail(user)
      @recipients = user.email
      @from = ...
    end
end

# Specific Mailer for User model
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def message(user, message)
    setup_mail(user)
    @subject = "You got new message"
    @body[:message] = message
  end
end

# Use the UserMailer to deliver some message
def MessagesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])
    @message.save
    UserMailer.deliver_message(@message.user, @message)
    redirect_to ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by setting the `ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries` to false:

```
def setup_mail(user)
  email = user.default_email
  if email.paused?
    ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = false
    logger.info "INFO: suspended mail for #{user.login} to #{email.email})"
  else
    ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
  end
  # other stuff here
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't set perform_deliveries universally, just per message, e.g.

```
after_filter :do_not_send_if_old_email

def do_not_send_if_old_email
  message.perform_deliveries = false if email.paused?
  true
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried many ways, but no one could help me except this one.

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  class AbortDeliveryError < StandardError; end

  before_action :ensure_notifications_enabled
  rescue_from AbortDeliveryError, with: -> {}

  def ensure_notifications_enabled
    raise AbortDeliveryError.new unless <your_condition>
  end

  ...

end
```

1. Make a class inherited with `standardError` to raise exception.
2. Check the condition, if false then raise exception.
3. Handle that exception with the empty lambda.

> The empty lambda causes Rails 6 to just return an
> ActionMailer::Base::NullMail instance, which doesn't get delivered
> (same as if your mailer method didn't call mail, or returned
> prematurely).